# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'User' C:\xampp\htdocs\gallery\admin\includes\admin_content.php on line 23

Tags: php

This is from User.php File

```
<?php 

class User {

    public static function find_user_by_id($user_id) {

        global $database;
        $result_set = $database->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$userid");
        $found_user = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set);
        return $found_user;
    }
}
?>
```

This is from admin_content.php In this page I am getting an error.

```
<?php 
    $found_user = User::find_user_by_id(2); // This is line 23

    echo $found_user["username"];
?>
```

This is the error I am getting.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'User' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\gallery\admin\includes\admin_content.php:23 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gallery\admin\index.php(24): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gallery\admin\includes\admin_content.php on line 23

Comment: Where do you include `User.php` so that your code knows about that class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use some kind of autoloader or use require/include functions

in admin_content.php add

`include "User.php";` `after <?php`